# HTTP Status Code: Response with 101 or 301?

Tags: 301-redirect, apache2, http

We can force SSL in apache servers with following config:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here, we tell the apache server that return a `301 Moved Permanently` response to the client.
But there is another status `101 Switching Protocols` and I think this status code is more suitable since we are switching from plain HTTP to HTTPS.

Am I right? Anything wrong?
Which status code should I use?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The correct status code to use here is without a doubt **`301 Moved Permanently`**.

`101 Switching Protocols` is an internal status code that a server generally uses to automatically negotiate certain types of connections. It's not used when changing the URL from `http` to `https`. If you're curious about how it works, you can read about [the 101 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101) and [the protocol upgrade mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism) on MDN, but you'll never need to know about it as a webmaster.

As a general rule, you should never directly use `100` series status codes unless you are actually developing web server software. The `300` and `400` series codes (especially `301`, `302`, and `404`) are the ones you'll want to pay attention to when running a simple website.

Comment: Tiny correction: `that a server generally uses to automatically negotiate certain types of connections` should read `that a *client* uses to request to change to another protocol`.

Comment: @AnoE `101` is a server status code; it's used by the server to "accept" the client's request to change to another protocol, not by the client to request a change to another protocol. From the MDN article: "The Upgrade header field is used by clients to invite the server to switch to one of the listed protocols, in descending preference order ... If the server decides to upgrade the connection, it sends back a 101 Switching Protocols response status"

Comment: Yes, my comment was not formulated in a great way. The client initiates the upgrade, the server responds with 101, was just nitpicking because your answer leaves the impression that the server initiates the upgrade.

Comment: *"You should never use `100` or `200` series status codes unless you are actually developing web server software"* - Maybe true of `100`, but definitely not true of the `200` series.  For example, if you are implementing a RESTful interface you will need to respond with `201 Created` on resource creation and maybe `202 Accepted` or `204 No Content` when a resource is deleted, depending on your model.  Also, if you support range requests in your application, you may need to report `206 Partial Content`.

Comment: @HappyDog You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 12):

No - `101 Switching Protocols` is not appropriate for redirecting to HTTPS, as this status indicates that the *current connection* should be upgraded to the new protocol, whereas a redirect instructs the client (browser) to retry the request at a new location.

The confusion may arise because, from your point of view, the two places are the same location, with the only difference being the protocol/port number used to access it.  However, from the perspective of the URI scheme, these are two separately-addressable locations (as the protocol is part of the address), hence a redirect is the correct method to use.

With an upgrade request, the `101 Switching Protocols` header is output and then the server *immediately* switches to using the new protocol on the *same* connection.

Comment: As in: If this *were* what happens, the communication would continue over port 80, and  encryption established within.

Comment: You *can* implement TLS in this manner, though it's not very common.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header#Use_with_TLS for a bit more detail.  It is most commonly used for websockets, which use a binary protocol, negotiated over HTTP using the `Upgrade` header and a `101` response code.

Comment: @HappyDog Is there an example of such a server?

Comment: I don't have an example, but I'm sure they exist.

Answer (score 3):

> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

It seems to me that the simpler regex `.*` should work just as well.

> Here, we tell the apache server that return a `301 Moved Permanently` response to the client.
> But there is another status `101 Switching Protocols` and I think this status code is more suitable since we are switching from plain HTTP to HTTPS.

No, the correct status code is `301`, for two reasons:

1. This is a redirect. Per [RFC 7231, section 6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6), redirects are indicated by the `3xx` series of status codes. [Section 6.4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) defines the `301 Moved Permanently` status code, which is clearly the appropriate one for HTTP → HTTPS redirects.
2. Apache does not take kindly to [redirects with status codes outside the `3xx` series](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html):

> However, if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

A redirect instructs the web browser to create a new HTTP request. In this case, that request requires a *new* connection to a new origin: changing either the scheme or the port changes the origin, and in this case, you change both. This is very different to the [`101 Switching Protocols` status code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.2.2), which immediately causes the *current* connection to switch to some other protocol. This other protocol could be anything (as agreed between the server and client), but will probably have nothing to do with HTTP!

Comment: "It seems to me that the simpler regex `.*` should work just as well." Or, indeed, simply `^` which might be a tiny bit faster, depending on the regex engine, since it doesn't need to walk all over the string.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I don’t actually use Apache. But lots of other people do, and I assumed a quick web search would sort this out. I was wrong. I kept finding things like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1` or even `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1`. How is there no canonical answer for this? Indeed, how is there no built-in feature for this?